# Unable to send data using AJAX post

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Can someone please help me with this code?

It changes the class, but no data is sent to the server. I Do not get any errors too.I think i might have messed up the var (declaration ) or the html

**Here is the html**

```
<a class="reg" id="<?php echo $pID?>" href="#">Registrate</a>
```

**Here is the script**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').click(
function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('reg')){
        $(this).removeClass('reg').addClass('done').text('done');
          var datasend = $(this).html();
         $.ajax({type:"POST", url:"data/update.php", data: 'id='+datasend, success:function(result){
        }});

    }


});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this :

```
var datasend = $(this).html();
```

with

```
var datasend = this.id;
```

Also send your data as an object, which will remove the need for the `datasend` variable.

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/url',
    type : "POST",
    data : {
        id : this.id
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

`$.ajax({type:"POST", url:"data/update.php", data: 'id='+datasend`

With:

`$.ajax({type:"POST", url:"data/update.php", data: {'id' : datasend}`

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
data: 'id='+datasend
```

with

```
data:{ id : datasend }
```